# axial tilts of 16, 28, and 75 on habitable planets

Tags: planets

How would an axial tilt of 16 Deg, 28 Deg and 75 Deg affect the seasons on an otherwise habitable earthlike planet? What would a Human like life form would evolve into? Would the tilt angles affect the evolution of intelligent life?

Comment: Could you please ask one question per question? This one is, essentially, three.

Comment: okay, how they effect the seasons of the planet and how would they effect life?

Comment: "How do they effect life" seems overly broad and again a seperate question.

Comment: This is a question of the sort: "Ok, take the world as we know it... then suddenly we just change one thing, but nothing else. What happens?". No, that is not how it works. In order to explore this you cannot just change **one** thing and assume everything else stays the same. You need to hit Ctrl+Z (Undo) **all the way back** to the very formation of the planet, and then let geology, plate tectonics and evolution play out all over again. Will it be different? Oh yes, it will be **very** different. Life may perhaps not come to be at all. And the evolutionary tree will be **vastly** different.

Comment: Not so much because of the tilt of the planet but because there is so much random change involved in evolution that you will **never** get the same result twice on two different planet. So your question is both very answerable and completely unanswerable. Will things be different? Yes, because such is the nature of evolution... it is **always** different. How will they be different? No clue at all.